# mysql_connect undefined

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I'm using mysql_connect PHP function but I get a fatal error saying that's it's not defined.

Using XAMMP on Windows 7 64-bit. haven't had a problem before and not the first time using it.

Code is as simple as this:

```
 <?PHP
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

 //1. Create a database connection
 $connection = mysql_connect(localhost , root, pass);
 if(!$connection){
  die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
 }

 //2.Select a database to use
 $db_select = mysql_select_db(fb_acc,$connection);
 if(!$db_select){
  die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
$username = mysql_real_escape_string('$username');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `fb_acc` (`username`) VALUES ('$username')");

?>
```

Comment: Show us your code on how you are using it.

Comment: If you don't wanna give an answer then simply don't.
I added the code to the question.

Comment: Do you have a password to connect to your MySQL database ?

Comment: I do. but if the pass is wrong then it would show the mysql error and not the fatal error thing. I'll just reinstall XAMMP. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Call to undefined function mysql_connect()`

It means that php_mysql.dll extension is either still under comment in php.ini or libmysql.dll is not copied to the system directory or to the directory with binary files of Apache/PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the extension directory is not set inphp.ini
Just copy the files of ext directory to root directory of php I.e. where you intalled php.

Answer (score -2):

Check your spelling for type errors. If not I suggest reinstall or switching to WAMP, or maybr new installation of the PHP.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook.php on line 17

Comment: http://bg2.php.net/mysql_connect - it is introduced after PHP 4 I don't see a reasonable reason other than your PHP version. If not you shourl consider new installation of your products (Apache, PHP, MySQL)

Comment: I have last PHP version. I'm gonna just reinstall everything..thx.